# CollapsingToolbarLayout do not expand after screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

There is activity in my application with header with background image and a title/beginning time of event. Below there is description of event.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="90dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar">

            <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/event_cover"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/event_header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:paddingRight="16dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="72dp">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:ellipsize="end"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_begin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textColor="#aaa"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/event_desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="72dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/event_action_btn"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/event_fab_margin"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And now I have strange buggy behaviour of CollapsingToolbarLayout. Following conditions are reproduced it:
1. In portrate orientation text of the description fits on a screen, so NestedScrollView can't scroll its content and CollapsingToolbarLayout do not collapse header

[image: screen 1]

2. In landscape orientation text of the description doesn't fit on a screen, so NestedScrollView can scroll content and it appears ability to collapse header

[image: screen 2]

In landscape orientation I collapse header (screen 3) and change screen orientation to portrate. Header stay collapsed and no posibility to expand it and header appears again (screen 4). In some cases under such manipulations Home button of Toolbar dissappear.

screen 3
[image: screen 3]

screen 4

[image: screen 4]

I use following versions of libraries: design support library - v22.2.1, appcompat-v7 - v23.0.1

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @TetianaDev that bug was fixed in next version of design support library